# Using a 'case when' in a Doctrine select statement

Tags: php, sql, doctrine

I have a select query I'd like to perform with Doctrine:

```
 $resultset = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->select("t.code, t.description, case when t.id_outcome = 1 then 1 else 0 end as in_progress")
    ->from('LuOutcome t')
    ->orderBy('t.rank')
    ->fetchArray();
```

And it barfs on the 'case'. The documentation does not mention that it's possible (or not).

I'm wondering if Doctrine lacks the capacity to do so. If so, it's a rather major omission. Does anyone know of a work-around?

Comment: please add a PHP tag to this question

Comment: done... in at least 15 characters :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem here. My project is very old, and tried to fix it quickly. So I just change a little bit the code for Doctrine so I can use "case when". This is my code for Doctrine 1.1.3.

Doctrine/Query.php, change lines from 658 to 674:

```
        if (count($terms) > 1 || $pos !== false) {
            if($terms[0]=='case')
            {
                $terms=explode(" as ", $reference);
                $expression = array_shift($terms);
                $alias = array_pop($terms);

                if ( ! $alias) {
                    $alias = substr($expression, 0, $pos);
                }

                $componentAlias = $this->getExpressionOwner($expression);

                $tableAlias = $this->getTableAlias($componentAlias);

                $expression=str_replace($componentAlias, $tableAlias, $expression);

                $index=0;

                $sqlAlias = $tableAlias . '__' . $alias;
            }
            else
            {
                $expression = array_shift($terms);
                $alias = array_pop($terms);

                if ( ! $alias) {
                    $alias = substr($expression, 0, $pos);
                }

                $componentAlias = $this->getExpressionOwner($expression);
                $expression = $this->parseClause($expression);

                $tableAlias = $this->getTableAlias($componentAlias);

                $index    = count($this->_aggregateAliasMap);

                $sqlAlias = $this->_conn->quoteIdentifier($tableAlias . '__' . $index);
            }

            $this->_sqlParts['select'][] = $expression . ' AS ' . $sqlAlias;
```

It's not a great change, but it helped me...

Answer (score 28):

I just had the same problem and, at first glance, appear to have a workaround. I believe you can 'fool' the Doctrine Select parser into treating it as a sub-query by wrapping it in parenthesis.

Give this a try:

```
$resultset = Doctrine_Query::create()
->select("t.code, t.description, (case when t.id_outcome = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as in_progress")
->from('LuOutcome t')
->orderBy('t.rank')
->fetchArray();
```

Answer (score 4):

Case statements do appear to have been added to doctrine at some point:
https://github.com/doctrine/orm-documentation/commit/189c729f15d2fafecf92662cad9553c2ec3dccd7#diff-0

Answer (score 3):

The [BNF grammar for the Doctrine Query Language](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_1/en/dql-doctrine-query-language:bnf) doesn't seem to contain anything related to a `CASE` construct.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by [adavea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/403849/adavea), Doctrine now has added support for [CASE](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#case-expressions) expressions. You can do something like

```
 $resultset = Doctrine_Query::create()
->select("t.code, t.description")
->addSelect("CASE WHEN(t.id_outcome = 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as in_progress")
->from('LuOutcome t')
->orderBy('t.rank')
->fetchArray();
```

Hope this might help someone, thanks!