# symfony2 doctrine create custom function for CASE WHEN THEN ELSE END

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine

I need to use `CASE` statement in symfony2 but doctrine does not provide this by default, so I have to create custom functions for `CASE`, `WHEN`, `THEN`, `ELSE` and `END`.

How can I create such custom functions? Give me some examples, if possible.

Comment: Doctrine [supports](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#case-expressions) CASE expression. Please, add more information about you problem.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4006383/4183702